# How to pass an event and an argument with bind method in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, event-handling

So this is is in my render method:

```
<Person 
       changed={(event) => this.nameChangedHandler(event, value.id)}
       />
```

And here's my Person Component

```
  <input type='text' onChange={props.changed} value={props.name}/>
```

And here's my Handler

```
>   nameChangedHandler = (event, id) => {  // Getting an Event Object
>     
>         const personIndex = this.state.person.findIndex(value => {
>     
>           return value.id === id;
>     
>         })
```

**It works Fine.**
But I want to know , if do this

```
<Person 
       changed={this.nameChangedHandler.bind(this, value.id)}
       />
```

Then How can I pass **event** with the **value.id** to the Component ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing two arguments to the `nameChangedHandler`, You can make it a curried function. This achieves the same result with a different approach.

For example

```
nameChangedHandler = (id) => (event) => {   
   // related code
})
```

You can pass the change handler to the `Person` component as props like this

```
<Person 
  changed={this.nameChangedHandler(value.id)}
/>
```

*A similar example in* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-brook-fthek?file=/src/index.js) - (**Note** watch the console after button click)